# changing a value of an object key changes an other at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a complex variable as an object including 2 times the same object.
if I change a value of the first object part, this will assume to change the value of the second part. is there an explanation? why are the tow keys still connected?!
here is a simple example of my code:

```
arr1={'a':[],'b':{'b1':'','b2':''}};
arr2={'p1':{...arr1},'p2':{...arr1}};

arr2['p1']['a']=[1,2,3];
console.log(arr2['p2']['a']);   // works => []

arr2['p1']['b']['b1']='blabla';
console.log(arr2['p2']['b']['b1']);   // doesn't work => 'blabla'
```

I don't want to write 'B={'b1':{'a':''},'b2':{'a':''}}' because A is a very big object in a separated .js file

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're trying to do. Can you include a sample of the actual  JS for us to look at? \

Answer (score 0):

[image] - use `spread operator` will save you from a problem like this

- The fundamental idea of the spread operator is to create a new plain object using the own properties of an existing object. So {...obj} creates a new object with the same properties and values as obj
- you can do that easily like

  ```
      A={'a':''};
      B={'b1':{...A},'b2':{...A}};
      B['b1']['a']='blabla';
      console.log(B['b2']);   // => '' not 'blabla'
  ```

Comment: thank you. It works, but for me still not 100% with expanding my example (see above!)

Comment: spread operator only tries to add new instance of children of first level, but it won't work for more than one level, ex. `[{a: { b: {c} }]` So in theory even by using spread operator you could still end up with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
A={'a':''};
B={'b1':A,'b2':A};
B['b1']['a']='blabla';
```

The main reason is that you try to change the object element via its index `a` instead of **changing the object (reference)**. Step by step,

- you ask to find `B['bi']`, which is `A` object
- and then you ask to set `A['a']` to `blabla`
- `B['b1']` and `B['b2']` point  to `A`
- you get "both" changed since it's same instance of `A`

But if you do `B['b1'] = { 'a': 'blabla' }`, then you will not get the same result. Because now you are adding a new instance without any connection to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with:

```
arr2={'p1':JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1)),'p2':JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1))};
```